# What is the best practice for logging errors and displaying to the user?

Tags: logging, try-catch

I have an angular 6 application. Is it bad practice to do something like this:

```
ShallowFunction() {
  try {
    //...do stuff
    DeepFunction();
    //...do more stuff
  } catch (error) {
    DisplayMessageToUser('There was a problem doing stuff.');
  }
}

DeepFunction() {
  try {
    //...do stuff
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('There was an error in DeepFunction: ', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I'm specifically looking at the catch block in DeepFunction. I catch the error, log it, then I throw it again. The reason I do this is that I want to log errors at the deepest point in the call stack because that's where I can know most precisely what happened. I can't know with that much precision in ShallowFunction. An error that is caught by the catch block there *could* be because of DeepFunction, or it could be because of "do stuff" or "do more stuff". I could let the error just trickle up from DeepFunction to ShallowFunction and *then* log the error but I don't get to log that the error happened in DeepFunction (which helps debugging). Yet even if I log it in DeepFunction, I still want to throw the error so that ShallowFunction can catch it and display a user friendly error message with DisplayMessageToUser.

What is the best practice to follow in order to accomplish what I want, which is:

1) Log the error where we know with as much precision as possible what happened and where it happened.

2) Display a user friendly error message to the user.